# Sharding AWS MySQL data

Tags: mysql, sharding

I am working on a SaaS application using AWS MySQL.

The application is for multiple organizations. We use the same database and tables to store multiple org data. We store `org_id` in most of the tables and use this in select, update and delete queries as `where org_id = ?` .

#### DB Model

- **Organization**

  ```
  org_id
  ```
- **User**

  ```
  user_id
  org_id
  ```
- **client**

  ```
  client_id
  org_id
  ```
- **client_contact**

  ```
  client_id
  phone_number
  phone_type
  ```
- **project**

  ```
  project_id
  org_id
  ```
- **user_project**

  ```
  project_id
  user_id
  ```

The data is growing rapidly and we need to shard the data. We have customers from all over the world.

If I use a different sharding id for different table, then a join might happen across the nodes. For example, for user, sharding can be on `shard_id` and for client, sharding can be on `client_id` and for project, sharding can be on `project_id`. Here, the problem would be joining project and user. The `user_id` and `project_id` might be on different nodes and join will happen across nodes.

What is the best approach here? I am thinking of sharding based on `org_id` as I store `org_id` in most of the tables.

I see two problems here:

1. A few child tables don't store `org_id` as the parent table is storing. Do I need to store the `org_id` in all the tables?
2. Some orgs might have more data and load which might lead to a hot spot and more storage on a particular node. Is it possible scale a particular node alone with AWS RDS?

Please suggest the best approach.

**Note** Each org might have up to 500,000 records in any table with around 10 columns. We could reach more than 5,000 organizations in 6 months. 500,000 multiplied by 5,000 orgs will reach 2.5 billion records.

Answer (score 0):

(Not *yet* an answer, but some more steps toward understanding the task enough to provide an answer.)

2.5 billion rows will fit on a single machine.  (Perhaps 400GB, including ancillary tables.)  Have you determined that the *activity* will exceed a single server's capabilities?

1. Which table is the biggest?  (Please list the 3 largest and their projected sizes.  Also, please provide the full `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of them -- We need to consider shrinking their datatypes.)
2. Which column(s) in that table seem reasonable for sharding?
3. If you shard on that column, what other tables will also be split up?
4. Ignoring for the moment, provide the 6 most common `SELECTs` with `JOINs` and multi-table Updates/Deletes.
5. Which tables will be needed for JOINs?  Are they small enough to simply maintain copies of them in each shard?  How complex will that maintenance be?